# How to set border radius for textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, border

Is there any way to set the border radius property for a text box in windows forms.

I've tried in ASP.NET but I couldn't get in windows forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following link, it might help:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17453/Textbox-with-rounded-corners

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, **No**, it is not possible in `WinForms` with standart TextBox control.  Take a look at [`WPF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), instead. That is much better than WinForms for example there is a [`Border.CornerRadius`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradius%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that might help you.And there are so other options in WPF which doesn't exist in WinForms.

Comment: I do prefer WPF than writing extra logic for rounded TextBox. WPF is very rich in look and feel

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in one blog .

[Please check this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab0521e0-d81a-40ac-bb84-d5873331ed6f/how-to-change-textbox-border-color-in-c-?forum=csharpgeneral)