# Can anyone please clearly help me to fix textbox style property in windows forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, .net, winforms

I've come across `BorderRadius` property in ASP.NET to set the `TextBox` look pretty good.

I want it to work in WinForms also.

How should I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set border radius for textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250993/how-to-set-border-radius-for-textbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in WinForms(there is no built in mechanism), but you can always make a custom control, and add such a property to it.
Check the following [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17453/Textbox-with-rounded-corners) for more info

You can also think about using WPF which has a [Corner.BorderRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradius%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you want to convert VB code to C#, then you can use this [site](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) and get the equivalent C# code of the VB code provided.

Comment: I want the code in C#

Comment: @KALYANAKUMAR IT doesn't matter whether the code is in C# or VB, the basic concepts remain the same, the .Net classes used remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: I have accepted your answer how to get reputation points to vote

Comment: see, that privilege to vote up will come automatically, as soon as you reach 15 reputation, you can get reputation points by asking good quality questions as well as answering the questions on SO.